# Filtering Data Table in PrimeNG

Tags: angular5, primeng, primeng-datatable

How can I get the number of rows after filtering using PrimeNG's default filters in data table.

`[totalRecords]="totalRecords"` always shows the records count which is fetched initially.

Even though after filtering, `totalRecords` value remains same and does not change after filtering.

Example: 
initially `totalRecords` is 50 and after filtering, no.of records it shows in data table is 15. But I cannot get the value 15, instead getting 50.

Is there any way ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Supposing you have a reference to your datatable component, just ask `totalRecords` property on it :

```
<p-dataTable [value]="cars" [rows]="10" [paginator]="true" [globalFilter]="gb" #dt>
    ...
</p-dataTable>

{{ dt.totalRecords }} records
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tzybaf)

Answer (score 3):

The above answer is correct and I'm adding up a little thing to it.

If you want to bind the `totalRecords` value to your typescript `.ts` file, then use an `(onFilter)` event and trigger a function with parameters as `$event` and `dt.totalRecords`

In my case, i have given

```
<p-table #dt [value]="personListData" [columns]="columns" (onPage)="onPageChange($event)" [resizableColumns]="true" [paginator]="true" [rows]="rowsCount" selectionMode="multiple" [(selection)]="selected_data" [loading]="loading" [totalRecords]="totalRecords" class="table table-hover table-responsive table-bordered" [responsive]="true" (onFilter)="handleFilter($event,dt.totalRecords)">
```

In short,

```
(onFilter)="handleFilter($event,dt.totalRecords)"
```

Function in .ts file ,

```
handleFilter(e,filteredRecordCount){
   console.log("filteredRecordCount");
}
```

> NOTE: If you want to use the filtered records count value, then you
>   can assign it to any variable and use anywhere in your typescript
>   file.

Answer (score 1):

I'm on Angular 8, and my table is not paginated. `dt.totalRecords` is always the full amount. So if I have 20 rows, and I get it filtered down to 2 on-screen, `dt.totalRecords` still = 20.

What I ended up doing was using the `onFilter`, passing in the entire dt, then using `dt.filteredValue`:

```
onFilter(event: any, table: any): void {
    if(!!table.filteredValue) {
        this.visibleRows$.next(table.filteredValue.length);
    }
}
```

You have to check for null, because if you change the filter but don't filter out any additional rows, `filteredValue` is null.

Answer (score -1):

html:

```
<p-dataTable #dt (onFilter)="handleFilter()" [value]="cars" [rows]="10" [paginator]="true" >
    ...
</p-dataTable>

{{ dt.totalRecords }} records
```

ts:

```
@ViewChild('dt', { static: true }) dt: Table;

handleFilter() {
    if (this.dt.filteredValue != null)
      this.dt.totalRecords = this.dt.filteredValue.length;
    else
      this.dt.totalRecords = this.cars.length;
  }
```

Comment: Is there any relevant documentation? A link to that would be very helpful.